# Recommended Approaches for building/designing a search engine for my website

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I would like to build a search engine for my website so I can quickly find relevant content. I've done quite a few google searches, discovered ElasticSearch and Solr (which both sit on top of Lucene), and whoosh (python-based).

But are all of these search engines just building an "inverted-index" on top of the data? What are some other algorithmic approaches for getting higher quality searches?

I was intrigued by this blog post using collaborative filtering on top of Solr, which returns *related* search queries:

```
http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/08/25/semantic-search-with-solr-and-python-numpy/
```

Are there other common techniques that I should be aware of? Are there other libraries sitting on top of ElasticSearch/Solr that I could just plug into, and use "out-of-the-box"?

Any links or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain more about your website?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned what tech stack you are working on.

If you use Ruby on Rails, I would recommend [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire), which is a gem that gives a DSL wrapper over ElasticSearch. Essentially, it allows you to index your data in Elasticsearch.

For Rails, [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) is a very popular gem that people use to interface with Solr.

For .NET - [SolrNET](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) is a great Solr client.

Other part of your question (around implementing a good search engine) is too broad - I would recommend reading a good book such as [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) to get a feel of what Solr/Elasticsearch could do.

I do have a few notes that I wrote a while back, you can read about some of my experience in search [here](http://www.hacknlearn.in/tag/search).

Edit:

Since you work on python, I would recommend [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/), although it is specific to Django. It is very versatile for our needs. However, if you are not using django, I can think of [solrpy](http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/) as a Solr client. Haystack works with both Solr and Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions! I prefer to work in python... I will take a look at "Lucene in Action". The link to your notes is broken...

Comment: Edited with some python client details. Notes link works for me, anyways try this - www.hacknlearn.in/tag/search

Comment: Note: Tire development has stopped due to  the elasticsearch-ruby gem https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to learn Solr API, cause it was developed since 4 5 years so you can find lots of plug-ins like related search API in Solr, But in elastic search it is very easy to configure however it is very young engine so needs to be developed more.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyes](https://github.com/aparo/pyes) is a well-documented Python client for Elasticsearch.

Also, this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDCpkXYXaCI) provides a good overview of using Elasticsearch with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Google Custom Search Engine. 
Here have a look.
https://www.google.com/cse/all

Answer (score 0):

We have developed several search engines both on Solr and Elastic. Solr used to be the best as it provided most of the tools needed to admin and debug your indexes. Right now Elastic offers the same features as Solr either natively or via plugins. Plus it is easier to configure in high performance/high availability scenarios (easy to shard or cluster).

Your technology stack is irrelevant. Both Solr and Elastic have clients nearly for every language, plus you can access both via plain HTTP:

That said, each search engine applies to a problem domain. Tunning Elastic or Solr to retrieve relevant results is a bit of an art with some trial and error.
You will have to define analyzers for each field you'll search on and according to your search patterns and the kind of results you will be expecting.

Eventually, to create search engines with a single input that search across disparate attributes of a document type, may need the use of DisMax queries where you can boost results depending on the matching of the search terms to specific document fields.

To summarize: go for Elastic, and get some plugins or frontends. Two suggestions:

- Inquisitor: for testing your analyzers
- Elastic Head: for administration purposes